# Execute list of runnables with time gap

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem to solve. in which i need to run list of runnable objects with some delay in each request execution.

Say for ex I have a list like below

```
List<MyReqObject> myReqObjects=new ArrayList<MyReqObject>();
```

and I have created an executor with X number of threads like below

```
ExecutorService execute=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(X)
```

now using  `execute.invokeAl(myReqObjects);` i an trying to invoke all these requests...

but I should have a delay in between these.
to achieve this I tried

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myObject, 2, 7, SECONDS);
```

but here I cannot send list as a argument so I can execute same request for 7 sec with delay of 2 sec...

so is there a way to solve my problem please suggest me

Comment: you can loop in the list of runnables to submit each runnable independently.

Answer (score 1):

create a Timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

if you need to run it once then:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   // Your code here
   }
}, 2*1000);
```

to run repeatedly:

```
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   // Your code here
   }
}, 2*1000);
```

see some coding examples for Timer and TimerTask [here](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Runnable that is a wrapper for your list of Runnables, and keeps track of what is sent.  Then give that single Runnable as the object for the scheduler.

```
public class RunnableList implements Runnable {

    private List<Runnable> runList = Collections.synchronizedList(
                                                  new ArrayList<Runnable>());

    public void addRunnable(Runnable r) {
        runList.add(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!runList.isEmpty()) {
            runList.remove(0).run();
        }
    }   
}
```

Essentially a collection object that is itself a Runnable.  Note that if you go the Executor route, you'd do a similar thing with Callable.

Answer (score 0):

One question.  Does these Runnables need to be executed N seconds *after* its previous runnable has completed or N seconds after the previous was scheduled.

If the latter you can continously schedule and increment a time counter.

```
int timeToWait = 2000;

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myObject, 2, 7, SECONDS); 
for(int i = 1; i <= runnables.size(); i++){
   scheduler.schedule(r, timeToWait * i, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

The former is a bit trickier.  You would need to have the runnable schedule it

```
final int timeToWait = 2000;
class SchedulingRunnable implements Runnable{
   private final Iterator<Runnable> runnables;
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler

   public SchedulingRunnable(Iterator<Runnable> rs, ScheduledExecutorService es){..}

   public void run(){
      runnables.next().run(); //assuming runnables.hasNext()
      if(runnables.hasNext()){
          scheduler.schedule(this, timeToWait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      }
   } 
}
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.schedule(new SchedulingRunnable(runnables.iterator(),schedule), timeToWait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This example has a wrapper Runnable execute the next available `run` and then schedule the next available after that with the specified wait time.